# Best way to prevent line break in Select with icon and text (React Material-UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Select with ListItemIcon and ListItemText.

When select is selected there is a line break.

I found several hacks to avoid this behavior, but I wanted to know the correct way.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oQ6l.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdwfP.png)

**Codesandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/select-icon-test-6jbseg?file=/src/App.js

**Code:**

```
function SelectIconTest() {
    const [selectOption, setSelectOption] = useState('0')

    function handleChange(e) {
        setSelectOption(e.target.value);
      }

    return (
        <>
            <InputLabel id="label-select-icon">Select with icon</InputLabel>
            <Select labelId="label-select-icon" id="select-select-icon" name="selectIcon" value={selectOption} onChange={handleChange}>
                <MenuItem value="0">
                    <em>None</em>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="1" key="1">
                    <ListItemIcon>
                        <AccountBalanceIcon />
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText disableTypography primary="Bank" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Select>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: You might have to either increase the width of your `Select` component or reduce the `Icon` size using the `size` prop. I would suggest adding a minimum width to the dropdown.

Comment: Just do this:  `#select-select-icon { display: flex; align-items: center }`

Answer (score 2):

in MUI way

try this in sx props

```
sx={{
    '&> div': {
        display: 'flex'
    }
}}
```

we are using MUI too, and this is how we navigate specific container

here is the sample [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/for-azarael-h1m3ch)